# Copy the Outlook mail body content to WORD Document using Python

Tags: python-3.x, vbscript, outlook

I want to write a python program that copies the contents of outlook mail body (Mail body : contains the tables) pastes it to word document.

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

class Handler_Class(object):
    def OnNewMailEx(self, receivedItemsIDs):
        for ID in receivedItemsIDs.split(",")
            mailItem = outlook.Session.GetItemFromID(ID)
            print(mailItem.Body)
outlook = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("Outlook.Application", Handler_Class)
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

when I try to print mail body using “print(mailItem.Body)” table contents are displayed as text, not as a table format.

Could anyone help me how to export the mailbody content to the word document without changing its format using python.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need to split the string passed to the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-getitemfromid-method-outlook) method and process the item. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Note that this behavior has changed from earlier versions of the event when the `EntryIDCollection` contained a list of comma-delimited Entry IDs of all the items received in the Inbox since the last time the event was fired. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body. So, you can use the Word object model do whatever you need with the message body. You can get access to the Document which represents the message body and copy/paste the required range or paragraph.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The Solution which you have provided is in VBScript. To do so, I need to pass the python object **Mailitem** to VBScript `public sub Word_Conversion(OutlookMail as Mailitem)` Could you help me out how to pass the python object to VB Macro.. I'm newbie to VB

Comment: The Outlook object model is the same for all programming languages. You already have the mailItem instance: `mailItem = outlook.Session.GetItemFromID(ID)`.

Comment: I have tried out by passing the mailitem to vb macro . I'm getting the error **pythoncom error: Python error invoking COM method.** . could you provide some insight ? .. I got stuck in this :(

Comment: Simple, The above python code i'm using to get the mail instance and This the VBScript macro `public sub Word_Conversion(OutlookMail as Mailitem)` which i'm going to call inside my python script. Inside this macro i am trying to print the attributes inside the mailitem (TO,BODY) then i'll create word object, copy and paste the content.